# Download file button with JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I need to generate the link and then download the link in one move. I have a button for generation and download and once is clicked i have to call the api to generate the download link for the pdf and then make the browser open the pop up with save item.

```
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="generateAndDownloadPdf()"><i
                class="fa fa-plus"></i>Generate and download invoice</span></button>
```

and my js controller function looks like :

```
            $scope.generateAndDownloadPdf = function(){
             //getting download url from api
            api.events.invoice.download($stateParams.eventId, $stateParams.speakerId).then(function(data){
                console.log(data)
                //give url to user

            });

        }
```

I know that once I have the download url I can use this html code, but  was wondering if I can do all in one click for the user.

```
            <a
           target="_self"
           href="download.url"
           download="file.pdf">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click=""><i
                    class="fa fa-plus"></i>Download Invoice</span></button>
        </a>
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can force the download with this way in yout method "generateAndDownloadPdf",

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = data.downloadUrl;
anchor.target = '_blank';
anchor.download = data.fileName;
anchor.click();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do using

```
window.location.href= url_to_download;
```